# Pass parameters to mapDispatchToProps()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can't lie, i'm a bit confused about react-redux. I think lot of the actions require parameters (for an example deleting items from the store), but even if i'm still reading about how to dispatch from component in that way to pass a parameter, about 2 hours now, i didn't get any answers. I was tried with `this.props.dispatch` and with `mapDispatchToProps`, i always get the `this.props... is not a function` message. Here's what i'm trying to do:

```js
  const getTheArray = (array) => {
    return {
      type: 'GET_ARRAY',
      array
    }
  }
    
    class Example extends......
    
    componentDidUpdate(){
    //i have a button, and when it clicked, turns the status: 'deleted'
        if (this.state.status === 'deleted'){
            fetch('http://localhost:3001/deleteitem', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    id: this.props.id
                })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.props.deleteFromArray(data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err)) 
        }
    }




function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        array: state.array
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return({
        deleteFromArray: (array) => {dispatch(getTheArray(array))}
    })
}
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Example);
```

It isn't the only place where i need to dispatch with an action, where the action's object's properties depending on another property passed to the function, so i really want to do, what's the best way to pass property to action, and dispatch it within a react component.

Comment: code you have pasted should work, but as you said `this.props.dispatch` is throwing the error, where exactly you are using `this.props.dispatch`?

Comment: In the place where now the this.props.deleteFromArray stays

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code so have to assume you've redacted the important part. My guess is that you're not binding the click handler and so `this` has the incorrect context (I'm guessing the fetch is done in the click and you've confusingly moved it)

Comment: It may be possible to the source of the problem is that i call the function inside componentDidUpdate? Or i call it inside fetch?

Comment: Does this.props.deletfromArray works fine..?

Comment: i believe your problem is a typo in this line `(array) => {dispatch(getTheArray(array))}` it should be `(array) => ( dispatch(getTheArray(array)) )`

Answer (score 2):

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux"

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return(bindActionCreators({
        deleteFromArray: (array) => {getTheArray(array)}
    }, dispatch))
}
```

In your dumbComponents, just call e.g this.props.deleteFromArray([1,2,3,4])

This should solve the issue. you are not binding with dispatch

Comment: i just realised that above code mentioned  by you also should work!! some other issue must be there

Comment: Note that this can be simplified using the "object shorthand" of passing an object full of action creators directly to `connect`:  `export default connect(mapState, {deleteFromArray : getTheArray})(MyComponent)`

Comment: @markerikson: But as you can see, I am trying to wrap the function inside dispatch. so that in dumb components one can use it directly this.props..deleteFromArray. That's the reason it has to be done like that. I know that you can pass objects alsoas the second param to connect. But that has a different use case

Comment: My example and yours are exactly equivalent as far as I can see.  They both create a bound function that will automatically dispatch the action creator when called, and pass it to your component as a prop.  Any arguments are automatically forwarded to the action creator.

Comment: Yes you are right . I again read the documentation . thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

#### use of react-redux

you need to import action first

```
import { storeProfiles } from 'actions/profiles';
```

#### define props

```
 const {
     storeProfiles
  } = props;
```

#### get data use of userEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchProfiles().then(storeProfiles);
  }, [ fetchProfiles, storeProfiles ]);
```

#### map to props

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
 
  storeProfiles: x => dispatch(storeProfiles(x))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

[Read official documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch)

Answer (score 0):

Using es6:
`const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ addToCart: (params) => dispatch(actions.addToCart(params)), });`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have to pass params to actions like that, in my opinion.
I'm using React Hooks with TypeScript and Redux and thunk. The way I delete a post using an action creator looks like this:

**PostDetails.tsx component:**

```
import {deletePost, getPost, LanguageActionTypeEnum} from "../../../../app/store/aspian-core/actions";

interface IPostDetailsProps {
    getPost: Function;

    // action for deleting a post
    deletePost: Function;

    loadingInitial: boolean;
    submitting: boolean;
    post: IPost | undefined;
    lang: LanguageActionTypeEnum;
}

const PostDetails: FC<PostDetailsProps> = ({
                                               match, getPost,
                                               lang, loadingInitial,
                                               submitting, deletePost, post
                                           }) => {



}


// To delete a post
    const onDeleteBtnClick = async (id: string) => {
        try {

            /// using deletePost action and passing id to it
            await deletePost(id);

            message.success(t('messages.post-deleting-success'));
        } catch (error) {
            message.error(t('messages.post-deleting-error'));
        }
    };

return (

   // omitted for brevity

   <Popconfirm
                    key={uuidv4()}
                    title={t('popconfirm.title')}
                    
                    /// calling onDeleteBtnClick() here
                    onConfirm={() => onDeleteBtnClick(post!.id)}  

                    okText={t('popconfirm.ok-text')}
                    cancelText={t('popconfirm.cancel-text')}
                    placement={lang === LanguageActionTypeEnum.en ? 'left' : 'right'}
                    okButtonProps={{
                        danger: true,
                    }}
                >
                    <Button
                        loading={submitting}
                        size="small"
                        type="primary"
                        icon={<DeleteFilled/>}
                        danger
                    >
                        {t('buttons.delete')}
                    </Button>
                </Popconfirm>

     // omitted for brevity
  )

}

// Redux State To Map
const mapStateToProps = ({post, locale}: IStoreState): { post: IPost | undefined, submitting: boolean, loadingInitial: boolean, lang: LanguageActionTypeEnum } => {
    return {
        post: post.post,
        submitting: post.submitting,
        loadingInitial: post.loadingInitial,
        lang: locale.lang
    }
}

// Redux Dispatch To Map
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getPost,

    // mapped deletePost action to props here
    // and I will be able to pass id to its argument later
    deletePost
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostDetails);
```

and my the action creator looks like this:

**postActions.ts:**

```
export const deletePost = (id: string) => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(setPostSubmitting(true));
        await agent.Posts.delete([id]);

        dispatch<IDeletePostAction>({
            type: PostActionTypes.DELETE_SINGLE_POST,
            payload: {
                id,
                submitting: false
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        dispatch(setPostSubmitting(false));
        throw error;
    }
}
```

And it works fine. Hopefully it could help you with your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use actions as arrow function so there would be no need to bindActionsCreators, let me do it with a very simple way.

**your action should be of arrow function like so:**

```
export const formHandler=({key,value})=>{
   /*for checking that you get the values on function call or not*/
    console.log(key,value)
  
      return {
      
      type:'formHandler',
      payload:{key,value},
      
      }
   
      }
```

**the below action function takes to arguments so you have to pass likewise**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch=> {
    /*this will add the functions as a props to the components 
    which can be trigger on order to change the state*/

    return {
        inputHandler: ({key,value})=>dispatch(formHandler({key,value}))
    }

}
```

**at the end you can use connect on yourComponent**

```
 export default connect(mapStatesToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(yourComponent)
```

**then in your component**

you can call the function using

**class component**

```
this.props.inputHandler({key:'k',value:2})
```

**functional component**

```
props.inputHandler({key:'k',value:2})
```