# Can i add dispatch manually to component's props instead of connect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So after a few hours of research, i get the problem that why my components aren't get the `this.props.dispatch`. The previous question: [Pass parameters to mapDispatchToProps()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669171/pass-parameters-to-mapdispatchtoprops) .
So i found the source of the problem, but don't know how to solve it. I have nested components created by a recursive function. For example:

```js
//App.js render
<Provider>
  </ExampleComponent counter = {6}>
</Provider>

//ExampleComponent.js

createChild = () => {
  const childs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.props.counter; i++){
    childs.push(</ExampleComponent counter = {this.props.counter - 1}>)
  }
  return childs
}

render(){
  return this.createChild()
}

export default connect()(ExampleComponent)
```

The problem here is, that only the direct component of the `Provider` receives the `dispatch` as a property, even if all the components are the same, and in an ideal way, they should be connected. Here's a picture how it looks like for better understand:
[image]

So what would be the best solution? How can i connect all of the components? (only my personal idea is to add the dispatch manually as a prop to the components, every solution is good what solves the problem)(and i need to tell that i use react-beautiful-dnd which also uses redux, so it might conflict with my store. I don't know, it might be.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect takes 2 arguments first one is for state, the second one is for dispatch.

The reason you are getting this error is that you are ignoring the props.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    // state has access to your store
    // ownProps has access to the props you are passing.
    return {
        ...ownProps,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        dispatch: (action) => dispatch(action),
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExampleComponent);
```

You can also import your actions here and create functions that dispatch your actions using bind action creator from redux, but I don't think that is needed.